# Using Flow to filter a date time field in Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a Sharepoint which has a datetime field format d/m/yyyy.

I've connected to Sharepoint and want to use the filter query option to find items where the month and day are the same as the current month and day?  The Flow will go through each item in the list and send a happy birthday message.

"formatdatetime(DateofBirth,'MM')  eq formatdatetime(utcnow(),'MM')".  This failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare two date in the flow, you need to add a "Filter Array" step under "Get items" step.The expression in the Filter Array as below:

```
@equals(formatDateTime(item()?['TestDate'], 'MM-dd'), utcNow('MM-dd'))
```

The 'TestDate' is my column.

Like this:

[image]

Reference:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/How-to-compare-two-dates-by-month-in-a-quot-get-items-quot/m-p/151219#M15179

Comment: That's great.  Thanks very much.

Comment: How do I accept it?  I cannot see a checkbox to tick.

Comment: Please read this article:https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers